# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for the String ranking =playerParts[0]

Tags: java

I keep getting a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the second while loop inside the while loop. Is there a step I am missing? I am reading my information from a file.  The whole goal of this program is for me to do the following:

1. Prompt the user for the file path.
2. Prompt the user to know how many teams should be created.
3. Ask the user for each team name (internally you can still use numbers/indexes for the teams if you wish, but you need to be able to output the team with the name at the end).
4. For the draft pattern each team should draft in order, but the order should be reversed in alternating rounds (i.e. the first team to draft in round 1 is the last team to draft in round 2, etc.).
5. Proceed to draft until either a) there are no more players/characters left or b) the user is prompted in between rounds if they want to continue and they indicate "No" (n alone is fine).
6. To select a player/character for a team

   1. show the user the different positions/roles the available people are in so one can be selected (you may use numerical entries to pick them if you want).
   2. once the user selects the position/role, display the available players/characters for the user to select one
   3. once selected, the player/character is added to the appropriate team
7. Once the draft is over either due to exhaustion of available selections or the user indicating it is complete show the following:

   1. Each team (team name, player - info for value, name, and creators/team, and team total (i.e. the value of all the people on the team)
   2. Finally, indicate which team has the overall lowest total value (i.e. the team with the "best" people, on average).

Sample files are available in Course Materials.

The format is as follows, with tab separated entries on rows with multiple values:
QB                      <- Position/role
1  A. Rodgers   GB      <- Value, Name, Team/Creator
2  T. Brady NE
3  D. Brees NO
-----                   <- 5 hyphens indicate the file is about to switch to a new position/role
RB                      <- next position/role

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class Superhero {
static TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Player>> positions = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Player>>();
ArrayList<String> team = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int teams = 0;
    String fileName = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Whats the name of the file: ");
    fileName = input.next();
    File superHeroFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner file = new Scanner(superHeroFile);


    while (file.hasNextLine()){
        //read the position
        String role = file.nextLine();
        // ready to create the ArrayList for all players in this role
        ArrayList<Player> playersInRole = new ArrayList<Player>();
        positions.put(role , playersInRole);

        // until I read "-----" I have a new all players in this current position
        String possiblePlayer = file.next();
        while (!possiblePlayer.equals("-----")){
            String[] playerParts = possiblePlayer.split("\t");
            String ranking = playerParts[0];
            String name = playerParts[1];
            String originalTeam = playerParts[2];

        }
    }


    for(int buildTheTeam = 0; buildTheTeam < teams; buildTheTeam++){
        int playerType = input.nextInt();
        switch (playerType){
        case 1: //Leader
            break;
        case 2: //Brawn
            break;
        case 3: //Gadgets
            break;
        case 4: //Female Influence
            break;
        case 5: //Bad Guy
            break;
        }
    }

    while (file.hasNextLine()){
        String wholeFile = file.nextLine();
        System.out.println(wholeFile);
    }

    //get the number of teams
    System.out.print("How many teams will you have? ");
    teams = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    for(int teamName = 0; teamName < teams; teamName++){
        System.out.print("What is the name of your team? ");
        String TeamName = input.next();
        System.out.println("Team " + TeamName   );
    }

}

}
```

I would appreciate any help Thank you!

Comment: Best time to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Is there any possibility that at the point where you get the exception, `possiblePlayer` has a value that doesn't include any tab characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line :

```
String[] playerParts = possiblePlayer.split("\t");
```

is not working as you expecting, because at some point `possiblePlayer` has less than 3 tabs (`\t`)

you must check if array `playerParts` has the needed number of elements before accessing them,
user `playerParts.length` to get array's elements number.

Answer (score 0):

when you call

```
possiblePlayer.split("\t");
```

you're getting fewer than 3 results.

are you sure that the fields are separated by tabs?

you can insert the following lines to determine what's **actually** going on.

```
String[] playerParts = possiblePlayer.split("\t");
System.out.println("possiblePlayer: " + possiblePlayer);
System.out.println("num fields: " + playerParts.length);
```